# 64-bit architecture page table size

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, memory-address, page-tables

I have seen some examples about 32-bit page tables, and most assume 4 bytes page table entry. I am wondering if 64-bit architecture works in the same way? If I want to implement 2-level and 3-level page tables in 64-bit one, what is the difference of page table size range?

Comment: '32-bit architecture' and '64-bit architecture' is too vague. If you mean IA32 and AMD64/EMT64, say as much.

Comment: Can I use 64 bit addresses in general? @user2864740

Comment: A 64-bit machine does not imply 64-bit addressing. For example on AMD64 it is 48-bit virtual, 52-bit physical IIRC (but hey, I'm not a computer engineer!). There is a similar non-clear distinction for a 32-bit IA32 machines, where more than 32-bit physically addressing is possible. I would start with review of available resources and focus on a more specific question (with a more specific implementation/target).

Comment: @user2864740 I think I should go with i386 this time

Comment: there's no 64-bit support in `i386`. It might be good idea to study the concepts and data structures of `page-directory entry` and `page-table entry` in [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) as it will equip you with some technical terms useful both for the quiz and for your consequential (re)search. More lightweight resource is the [OSDev.org wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

Intel 64-bits supports 4kb, 2mb, and 1GB pages.